# Claiming IP address from CentOS 7 server

Tags: centos, configuration, ip, webserver, router

**How do I configure a CentOS7 server to connect to the internet and be known as a specific IPv4 address in the form of: `aa.aa.aaa.aa2`?**

---

**HERE ARE THE DETAILS (Updated 2/27/2017):**

---

**Cable Modem**

A [Cisco DPC3941B (see link)](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/video/residential-gateways-digital-voice/datasheet-c78-734440.pdf) router from an internet access provider has a Gateway IP `aa.aa.aaa.aa6`, and has several IP addresses allocated to it in the form of `aa.aa.aaa.aa1`, `aa.aa.aaa.aa2`, `aa.aa.aaa.aa3`, `aa.aa.aaa.aa4`, and `aa.aa.aaa.aa5`.  It also has subnet mask `255.255.255.248` and DNS `bb.bb.bb.bb, bb.bb.cc.cc`.

**CentOS 7 Config**

`nmcli con show` gives results including `eno1    uuid    802-3-ethernet    eno1`.

`nmcli con show eno1` gives a lot of output, including:

```
IPV4.ADDRESS[1]:  aa.aa.aaa.aa2/29  
IPV4.GATEWAY:     aa.aa.aaa.aa6  
IPV4.DNS[1]:      bb.bb.bb.bb  
IPV4.DNS[2]:      bb.bb.cc.cc
```

But yet when I `ping google.com` from the same terminal, the response is `connect: Network is unreachable`.  And when I try to Putty to `aa.aa.aaa.aa2` from another computer, the connection times out without connecting.  Similarly, typing `ping aa.aa.aaa.aa2` from another computer also times out with 0% packet return.

In case this is a firewall issue, I typed `firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all` and got:

```
public (default, active)  
  interfaces:eno1  
  sources:  
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh  
  ports:  
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks  
  rich rules:
```

**How A Windows Machine Is Configured to Do The Same Thing Successfully**

To rule out the possibility that the problem might be caused by the cable modem, I connected a Windows laptop to the modem with the following steps outlined below, and am able to connect to the internet and be seen as `aa.aa.aaa.aa1` when using the Windows laptop through a different ethernet cable connected to the same modem.

Here are the steps that get the Windows laptop to connect to the internet as `aa.aa.aaa.aa1` through the same cable modem:

```
1.  Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center    
2.  Click “Change Adapter Settings”  
3.  Right click on “Ethernet 2” connection and click on “Properties”  
4.  Select “Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)”  
5.  Then click on “Properties” Button to open the target dialog box:  
    a.  In the default state, the “Obtain IP address automatically” option is checked  
    b.  To claim a specific IP instead, click “Use The Following IP Address” and enter the following information:  
            i.  IP Address:  aa.aa.aaa.aa1  
            ii. Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.248  
            iii.    Default Gateway: aa.aa.aaa.aa6  
            iv. Preferred DNS Server: bb.bb.bb.bb  
            v.  Alternate DNS Server: bb.bb.cc.cc  
            vi. Check the “Validate Settings on Exit” option.  
            vii.    Click OK  
6.  Click on any other open dialog boxes to return computer to normal state
```

**Pinging The Cable Modem's Local IP**

The Windows command prompt is able to successfully ping the Cable modem by typing `ping 10.x.x.x`, which is the local IP for the cable modem.

But when I type the identical `ping 10.x.x.x` from the CentOS 7 server's terminal, the response is `connect: Network is unreachable.`

**Ethernet cable lit on both ends**

The Ethernet jack on the server is lit up indicating that it is connected, and the Ethernet jack on the other end of the server cable attached to the cable modem is also lit up indicating that it is connected.  So there is an electrical connection between the CentOS 7 server and the cable modem.

The problem seems isolated to the CentOS 7 config.

**Setting Up A Route To The Cable Modem From CentOS**

The Internet Service Provider gave [this link](https://business.comcast.com/help-and-support/ethernet/comcast-business-ethernet-equipment-configuration) containing information about how to set up a connection between a generic machine and the local modem.  The link is for a different kind of connection, but the ISP said it could be adapted.

Comment: This sounds as if the "gateway" is in effect a switch and not a "router". Given the pattern xx.xx.xxx.xxx can you confirm that the first 2 digits are **not** 10? Does something like the phrase "static ip address allocation" appear in the information sent to you by the ISP? with the xx.xx.xxx.xxx are the first 7 digits the same for each of the addresses? How many addresses are there (hopefully 2, 6, 14, 30, in general a number of the form 2**n-2)?

Comment: @icarus The first 2 digits are NOT 10.  The first 7 digits are the same for all of the ip addresses, and for the gateway IP.  The gateway IP can be pinged directly from outside in the internet.  Also, when I hook up a Windows box to the router and use the control panel to set one of the allocated IP addreses, I am able to ping that IP from the outside internet also.  This is a situation of buying 5 IP addresses along with an internet access account.  Does this clarify?

Comment: Yes it clarifies. So you want to do essentially the same with the Centos7 boxes as you do with the Windows box. In the windows box you needed to put in the ip address, the netmask and the gateway. With Linux this is a 2 step affair. Step one sets the address and netmask, and step two sets the gateway. (The 5 addresses sound good, I should have said 2**n-3, so 1, 5,13, 29 are for you and one more is the gateway, the other 2 missing addresses are the address for the lan itself and the broadcast address).

Comment: @icarus So if I hook up a keyboard and a monitor to one of the CentOS 7 servers, what specific sequence of commands do I type in to accomplish the desired results stated in the OP?

Comment: If you can reboot the servers then the easy thing to do is edit /etc/network/interfaces and reboot. You need to know the name of your interface. If you run `ip -o addr show` then there will be a series of lines, like "2: eth0: inet....". You want the "eth0" part. Ignore the name "lo". You want to add/alter a set of 4 lines. `iface eth0 inet static` `address xx.xx.xxx.xxx` `netmask 255.255.255.248` `gateway xx.xx.xxx.xxx` the last being the gateway ip address. It might be that you should put these 4 lines into a /etc/network/interfaces.d directory in a file named after the interface.

Comment: @icarus There is no /etc/network directory.  This is CentOS 7.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can create /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$IFNAME if you don't want to use network manager - see https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7

Comment: @icarus I revised this question with a lot more specific information. (See above in OP.) Are you willing to continue to help resolve this?

Comment: certainly. If things get desperate I can fire up centos in a VM! I am busy right now, but I will look at the updated question in about 11 hours - unless someone else solves it first.

Comment: Nicely written question :-)  Can you confirm that the CentOS box has been able to connect in the past.  Maybe before you set up this cable modem? A local IP address (192.168.x.y or 10.x.y.z) maybe?  Just because the lights on the NIC are on, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's working.  This is simply to eliminate that option.

Comment: @garethTheRed The CentOS box was able to connect to the internet as the Gateway IP in the past.  But not as one of the dedicated IP addresses, which is what I need.

Comment: Try running `ethtool eno1`(if it's installed, or you can install it) and check the speed and duplex settings.  Compare it to what the Windows laptop has using [this](http://superuser.com/questions/86581/how-do-you-check-the-current-duplex-value-of-a-network-card-set-to-auto-negotiat).

Comment: @garethTheRed `ethtool eno1` gave 1000Mb/s on CentOS.  And then on Windows, `wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed` gave 1000000000.  That is nine zeros.

Comment: @garethTheRed And Full Duplex on CentOS.

Comment: I've just re-read your question.  It seems the Windows laptop is on a 10.x.y.z private network, while the CentOS box is attempting to be on your public network.  As Windows is working, it suggests that your router is configured for NAT (Example #2 in your linked Cisco instructions) and not direct routing (Example #1).

Comment: @garethTheRed Given that the Windows box is able to be recognised as the intended IP, how do we get the CentOS box to do what the Windows box is doing?

Comment: from the windows box, can you run "tracert 8.8.8.8" and tell us the first 4 lines of output? If you want to change the addresses to obscure them then please make it clear which parts of the addresses are the same and which differ. What I am trying to do is figure out what the address is after the aa.aa.aaa.aa6 is.

Comment: @icarus The first line of results from `tracert 8.8.8.8` is `aa.aa.aaa.aa6`, which is the same as the expected Gateway OP of the cable modem.  The second line is an IP that I do not recognize without out explanation.  The next 5 lines are IP addresses that each have domain names that contain the name of the internet service provider, which means to me that they are all inside the ISPs network.  Then lines 8 and 9 are both just IP addresses without any descriptors.  And line 10 is `google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]`.  Every one of the ten lines if unique.  Is this enough information?

Comment: It would be simplest if you could just tell us the address from the second line. If you can't then can you tell us if it is related at all to the aa.aa.aaa.aa6 address, or if it is of the form 10.x.x.x, 172.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x? Can you also tell us if on the Centos box the output of `ip route` has a line with `default` in it, and if so that line contains aa.aa.aaa.aa6, or has the address from the second line of the tracert in it or something else?

Comment: @icarus I did a `whois` for the three IP addresses that did not have descriptors in the `tracert 8.8.8.8` results shown above.  The second one (that you are asking about) is a public IP owned by the ISP in the form of aa.xxx.xx.x (Where aa is the first 2 digits of both the gateway and all the public IPs listed in the OP).  The 8th and 9th results of `tracert 8.8.8.8` are public IPs owned by google. ... On the CentOS box, `ip route does NOT produce a `default` line in its results. CentOS `ip route` produces only one line of output, and that line contains `dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src`

Comment: OK, the lack of `default` is almost certainly the issue. tracert on windows is essentially the same program as traceroute on unix, (simplifing slightly) it tells you how a packet gets to the destination. Once it gets into the ISP networks you no longer care how it gets to google, you just need to get the packets to the ISP in the first place! Can you run `ip route add default aa.aa.aaa.aa6 via en0` on the centos box and see if you can ping or tarceroute to 8.8.8.8? (8.8.8.8 is an easy to remember address of googles DNS service, using an address rather than a name avoids DNS issues).

Comment: @icarus `ip route add default aa.aa.aaa.aa6 via eno1` on the CentOS box resulted in `Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "aa.aa.aaa.aa6" is a garbage.`  Note that the dateway IP is a public IP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54510/discussion-between-icarus-and-codemed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, need to configure a static IP address on Centos7, which is covered in the [FAQ](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7). Once this was done everything worked.

Comment: Links change, so the best practice on this site is to copy the relevant portions of what is on the linked page into your answer, and then to provide the link to give credit to the original resource.  I am marking yours as accepted because you spent so much time helping me find the answer, but another reader would have to spend a very link time sorting through the comments and chat and your link to figure out how to solve a similar problem, because your answer is so terse.

Comment: @CodeMed Feel free to edit my answer.